# Injecting a call to CustomAttribute's constructor with parameter values [Mono.Cecil]

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I've been trying to find a good way to inject a call to a CustomAttribute's constructor with its specified parameters. The CustomAttribute from Mono.Cecil gives access to its constructor as well as its parameters. The parameter's value is quite normally given as System.Object. I could not find an overload of ILProcessor.Create that takes an object (which I find perfectly normal).

The only solution I could come up with is to check the type of the parameter and, depending on the type, cast it (or break it down if its an array) to its literal type (since attribute constructor parameters are limited to value types and one-dimensional arrays) and then use an appropriate CIL instruction to load the parameter. I've already implemented it this way but it seems like a tedious and bad way of solving this issue. Yet again, I'm a beginner to CIL and Mono.Cecil, so my habits as a C# / higher level developer as well as my lack of experience could be the reason I see it this way.

Is there a better way to achieve this (Except calls to the reflection API, which I find is not a good solution)? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Example of what I mean, suppose there's a setting like this

```cs
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute {

    public string s;
    public int[] intArray;

    public CustomAttribute(string s){
        this.s = s;
    }
}

[CustomAttribute("Hello World", intArray = new [] { 1, 2, 3 })]
public void DoSomething() {}
```

then I want to inject the appropriate instructions to call this at runtime :

```cs
new CustomAttribute("Hello World")
{
    intArray = new [] { 1, 2, 3}
};
```

I'd like to point out that I have achieved this by iterating over the parameters and deciding what instruction to inject based on the parameter's type (since an attribute's constructor accepts very specific parameters) but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hello, I'll try and explain it better. Given an Attribute over i.e a method, I want to recreate the IL instructions needed to create an instance of that Attribute with its constructor and constructor parameters, at run-time. I'll update the post with an example.

Comment: are you using CustomAttributeNamedArgument?

maybe this can help you:

https://cecilifier.me/?gistid=fa24568d203517b8a83814a43a70c126 (unfortunately there's a bug if you try to use arrays but maybe the general idea may help)

Comment: Yes, I've been using CustomAttributeNamedArgument. I'm close to finishing this, thanks for the tool! Seems like there is no "cleaner" way to achieve this.